# How to parse nested XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I'm working with an API and retrieving the data in XML. Here's my XML:

```
<RTT>
  <AgencyList>
    <Agency Name="Caltrain" HasDirection="True" Mode="Rail">
      <RouteList>
        <Route Name="BABY BULLET" Code="BABY BULLET">
          <RouteDirectionList>
            <RouteDirection Code="SB2" Name="SOUTHBOUND TO TAMIEN">
              <StopList>
                <Stop name="Sunnyvale Caltrain Station" StopCode="70222">
                  <DepartureTimeList/>
                </Stop>
              </StopList>
            </RouteDirection>
            <RouteDirection Code="NB" Name="NORTHBOUND TO SAN FRANCISCO">
              <StopList>
                <Stop name="Sunnyvale Caltrain Station" StopCode="70221">
                  <DepartureTimeList>
                    <DepartureTime>69</DepartureTime>
                  </DepartureTimeList>
                </Stop>
              </StopList>
            </RouteDirection>
          </RouteDirectionList>
        </Route>
        <Route Name="LIMITED" Code="LIMITED">...</Route>
        <Route Name="LOCAL" Code="LOCAL">...</Route>
      </RouteList>
    </Agency>
  </AgencyList>
</RTT>
```

Not every DepartureTimeList will have a DepartureTime child node. Here's what I got so far, which retrieves the Route name:

```
List<string> trainType = new List<string>();
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://services.my511.org/Transit2.0/GetNextDeparturesByStopName.aspx?token=0f01ac4a-bc16-46a5-8527-5abc79fee435&agencyName=Caltrain&stopName=" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString());
doc.Save("times.xml");
string feed = doc.ToString();


XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(feed));
r.ReadToFollowing("RouteList");
if (r.ReadToDescendant("Route"))
{
    do
    {
        trainType.Add(r.GetAttribute("Name"));
    } while (r.ReadToNextSibling("Route"));
}
```

I'm mostly interested in the departure time (if it exists) and I've been struggling all afternoon to try and parse it.

Comment: Did you try using LINQ to XML for query instead?

Comment: I've never actually used LINQ to XML for parsing XML.

Comment: Note that ASP.NET is clearly not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this... Hopefully this will do it.

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("xml path");
    XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/RTT");
    foreach (XmlNode nodes in node.SelectNodes(
        "/AgencyList/Agency Name/RouteList/Route"))
    {
        trainType.Add(r.GetAttribute("Name"));
        XmlNode s = nodes.SelectSingleNode("Route Name/RouteDirectionList/RouteDirection Code/StopList/Stop");
        if (s != null && s["DepartureTimeList"].HasChildNodes)
        {
            // do stuff here
        }
    }
```